# jquery ui: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui dialog, I download it from jquery ui website, version is jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js, and jquery is jquery-1.9.1.js which is bundled with jquery ui js, but now I am encountering a question: when dialog is opened and click save button, I want the dialog to be closed, here is my code:

```
$(function(){
 $("#dialog-form").dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     height: 350,
     width: 450,
     modal: true,
     buttons: {
       "save": function() {
           if(!checkDept()){
               return ;
           }
           $.post('dept_save.do', 
                 {'dept.deptId':$("#dialog_dept_deptId").val(), 
                  'dept.deptName':$("#dialog_dept_deptName").val(),
                  'dept.manager':$("#dialog_dept_manager").val(),
                 },function(data, status, xhr){
                     if(status == 'success'){
                         alert('save success');
                         $(this).dialog("close");
                     }else{
                         alert('error:'+data);
                     }
                  }
                 ,"json");
       }
     },
     close: function() {
         $(this).dialog("close");
     }
   });

     /* to open dialog*/
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    });
```

now when I close the 'save success' popuped dialog, `dialog-form` dialog was not closed, and an error occurs:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close' jquery-1.9.1.js:507.

and there is another error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o jquery-1.9.1.js:541

thanks.

Comment: sorry, I know why it is wrong, `$(this)` in the anonymouse success function does not refer to the dialog, change it to `$("#dialog-form")` will work fine.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are losing the context of `this` once you are inside of `$.post()`.
Before your $.post, save the context `this` in a variable inside of that *save* button function.

```
$('#dialog-form').dialog({
     // .....
     buttons: {
        'save': function() { 

            var $this = $(this); 
                      // -this- is still the original context 
                      // of $("#dialog-form")

            $.post({
               /// ...
               $this.dialog('close'); // <-- used here
            });
        }       
    }
});
```

Comment: Same thing with an ajax call instead of a post.

Comment: There are alternative ways to solve the problem. Please, see my answer  below.

Comment: @JotaBe But the OP wasn't asking how to get the new content div though, he's trying to close the dialog itself within an ajax scope, he was simply pointing to the wrong `this`.

Answer (score 10):

When you initialize a dialog by calling the `.dialog(options)` method, a new dialog is created, but it's not associated to the original div that you want to convert into dialog (the '#dialog-form' in your sample code). The `dialog(options)` function returns the element containing the dialog data. So, if you do it this way:

```
var myDialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog(options);
```

You can then call the open method like this:

```
myDialog.dialog('open');
```

If you want to find the element contianing the dialog, it's the closest div with "ui-dialog-content" class:

```
var myDialog = $('#dialog-form').closest('div.ui-dialog-content');
```

The dialog data is the `uiDialog` data which you'll see if you look at this element data:

```
myDialog.data();
```

Comment: Saved the day! I was trying to call a `JS` function that had this code after a postback and this did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

`$(this)` isn't targeting the dialog inside of `$.post`, you'll need to store a reference to it.

```
var self = this; // add this
$.post(..., function(){
    $(self).dialog("close"); // modify this to use self
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to do the following to get my dialog closed.

```
 $("#Note").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,            
        modal: true,
        create: function (e, ui) {
          //
        },
        open: function () {
            //
        },            
        buttons: {
                //
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").trigger('click');
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can cause this error is if for any reason you call removeData() on the dialog box.  Apparently the jquery data() function is used to initialize the dialog, so if for any reason that data gets removed, the dialog will not think it has been initialized.

I found this out when I was storing form data in the dialog object with the data() function and then called removeData() on the dialog right before closing it.

Answer (score 0):

you might have used a popup instead of a dialog. I think the methods for closing the two are different. try use `$("#popid").popup('close');`