# jQueryUI Dialog box closing on Button Click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Im trying to create a dialog box with some additional interactivity inside; namely adding/removing options from a multi-select. basic code below:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addCallDialogForm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        model: true,
        width: 500,
        buttons: {
            "Add Call": function() {
                alert("Adding Call")

                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },

        open: function(event, ui) {
            //Doing additional Stuff Here
        },

        close: function(event, ui) {
            //Doing additional Stuff Here Too
        }
    });

    $("#addBtn").click(function() {
        alert("button Clicked");
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="addCallDialogForm" title="Add Call">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <button id="addBtn">Add</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I click the 'Add' button, the alert displays, but as soon as I click OK, the dialog closes. I tried using the 'beforeClose' method to specify when the dialog should close, but that didnt help.

Can anyone help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which alert is being called?

Comment: & are you opening popup inside dialog?

Comment: The Alerts are just generic code, they could easily be replaced with "console.log". When I click Add, Im moving selected options from one multi-select to another. which works, but as soon as the move is complete, the dialog closes

Comment: You are calling $(this).dialog("close"); this is closing your model dialog.

Comment: @Parkask Kumar - Yes I know, but that is only being executed when i Click the 'Add Call' or 'Cancel' Dialog Buttons. the 'Add' Button is a standard html button that I have added to the Dialog form manually.
Anyway I've tried to remove them and the problem persists.

Comment: Create a fiddle for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found that clicking any button in the dialog submits that form. By adding `event.preventDefault()` as the first line in the required method/s, the button does what I want without submitting and closing.

Related Post: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501932/jquery-ui-cannot-call-methods-on-dialog-prior-to-initialization-attempted-to-c)

Thanks for trying - G

Answer (score 0):

Button tag:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Style="margin-left: 12px;
    background-color: #FE8000; color: white" 
OnClientClick="closeCommentPopup()" />
```

closeCommentPopup function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeCommentPopup() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
        return false;
    };
</script>
```