# Problems with jquery dialog when click on a button

Tags: jquery

I already tried things mentioned in this question here [jquery ui: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501932/jquery-ui-cannot-call-methods-on-dialog-prior-to-initialization-attempted-to-c) but it didn't help me at all im still getting the same error when i click on "Da" button which is:

Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

Does anyone have an idea what am i doing wrong?

```
$(document).on('click', '#brisanje', function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Da: function () {
                    var $close = $(this);
                    $.post("ajax.php", {
                        mode: 8,
                        postID: $("#hidden_id").val()
                    }, function (response) {

                        $close.dialog("close");
                        searchData();
                    }); 
                },
                Ne: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Code for searchData()

```
function searchData()
{
    $.post("search.php", {
           mode: 1,
           postSelect: $('#select').val()              
    }, function (response){         
            $('#results').html(response);               
    });             
}
```

Comment: Not exactly related to the question, but `$(function () {});` is totally unnecessary

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ve0cs7hc/1/

Comment: what are the jquery and jquery-ui versions used

Comment: Its not jquery since i use dialog on other pages without problems, so it must be something about searchData() that is making the problem, i will edit my question with that code